# Android Studio New Project XML issue

Tags: android, xml

The below error is shown when attempting to run a new project in Android Studio. Had no issues until now, updating the IDE hasn't worked either.

\Joe\AndroidStudioProjects\FunFactsNew\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:5:18: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

[image: Overview of file in question here]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: the code in your colors.xml is not right,  Do you know what you want to write their and what should be in color.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to official docs `colors.xml` don't support `<module>` tag.
Look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color

Try to change it like this for your new project:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```